# Can I allow or deny access only to some nodes in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've created a new user for my coworker using `CREATE USER` mjhelix `IDENTIFIED BY 'UTJkBgJFJUse';`.

She can now access the Memgraph database using her credentials.
I'd like to limit her access to creatin parts of the database, i.e. I don't want here to be able to make changes to certain nodes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thing called label-based authorization. You can use it to apply rules to a role in Memgraph. The `GRANT` command is used fo that. There are several permission levels that you can grant. The permission levels are `NOTHING`, `READ`, `UPDATE`, or `CREATE_DELETE`.

You can specify a set of node labels, separated with a comma and with a colon in front of each label (e.g. `:L1`), or `*` for specifying all labels in the graph.
Identify the role you want to assign the rule to. This should be a role that has already been created in Memgraph. Let's say that mjhelix is working as an analyst, you need to assign the role first:

```
SET ROLE FOR mjhelix TO analyst;
```

In such case you can use the following command to assign the rule:

```
GRANT permission_level ON LABELS label_list TO role;
```

Let's say that you want to grant `READ` permission on labels `L1` and `L2` to a role named `analyst`, you would write:

```
GRANT READ ON LABELS :L1, :L2 TO analyst;
```

And if you want to grant both `READ` and `EDIT` permissions for all labels in the graph to the same role, you would write:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON LABELS * TO analyst;
```

You can find more details in the [Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/configuration/security).

Disclaimer: I work at Memgraph.